# SF Pro Display looks different to native Apple System Font - kerning (letter-spacing) doesn't match

Tags: css, ios, macos, google-chrome, fonts

I installed the SF Fonts from https://developer.apple.com/fonts/ but when I install and use them, they look different from the native "apple-system" fonts when setting the body `font-family` in the CSS. When I change this to use "SF Pro Display", the letters look much closer together.

```
/* Using downloaded font: */
body {
  font-family: 'SF Pro Display';
}

/* Using native font: */
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, 'system-ui';
}
```

[image]

On closer inspection, Chrome renders the font: `.SF NS Display—Local file(10 glyphs)`

Is this a different font completely? Seems strange that this isn't included in the Developer font download. However the main difference seems to be the letter-spacing.

Comment: Did you find out why that happens and how to solve this? I have the same issue.